# xampp mysql error

Tags: mysql, xampp

When using XAMPP I get this error when I try to open the MySQL admin:

> mysql service not started [-1]

I had xampp 1.7.2 installed before and it worked fine, now I have installed 1.7 instead and it has this problem.

How can I fix this ?

*Update:*

I rolled back because at this time joomla does not seem to support PHP 5.3. I did restart on the pc before installing and also tried to install two xampp patches but with with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with wampserver which is similar. I have a few questions also: did you uninstall before installing 1.7? Why did you revert from 1.7.2 to 1.7? Also did you restart all services (or the computer) before trying to open the admin?

I have had occasions when the sql service is in use by another process (in my case an SMTP server) and I forgot to shut it down during changes to my config, which resulted in problems. You may want to double check that nothing else is using the services and then perform a clean install.

Hope this helps.